# Selective recursive move?

Tags: command-line, rename

Is there a command like

```
mv --preserve-structure src src/1 src/2/3 dst
```

which creates `dst/1` and `dst/2/3`? It should work similar to `mv src/* dst`, but move only the subtrees listed.

Comment: you can do this with rsync.

Comment: So, you want each specified dir without descending into subdirectories?

Comment: @glenn jackman Actually both, I'm moving a couple of things around like crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Linux, using `rename` from the Linux utilities (`rename.ul` under Debian and Ubuntu):

```
rename src dst src/1 src/2/3     # dst/2 must exist
```

With the `rename` Perl script that Debian and Ubuntu install as `prename` or `rename`:

```
rename 's!^src!dst!' src/1 src/2/3    # dst/2 must exist
rename 'use File::Basename; use File::Path;
        s!^src!dst! && mkpath(dirname($_))' src/1 src/2/3
```

Here's a shell function that does what you're asking except for the argument order:

```
mv-preserving-structure () {
  s=${1%/} t=${2%/}; shift 2
  for x; do
    case $x in
      $s/*)
        y=$t${x#$s}
        mkdir -p -- "${y%/*}"
        mv -- "$x" "$t${x#$s}";;
    esac
  done
}
mv-preserving-structure src dst src/1 src/2/3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumes bash and GNU find.

```sh
mv_preserve_structure() {
  local src_file="$1"
  local dest="$2"
  local rel_dir="$(dirname "$src_file")/"
  rel_dir="${rel_dir#*/}"  # returns "2/3" if rel_dir was "src/2/3"
  mkdir -p "$dest/$rel_dir"
  mv "$src_file" "$dest/$rel_dir"
}

# unlike mv, this requires the destination dir as the first parameter
mv_dirs() {
  local dest="$1"
  shift
  for dir in "$@"; do
    for filename in "$dir"/*; do
      [[ -f "$filename" ]] && mv_preserve_structure "$filename" "$dest"
    done
  done
}

mv_dirs dst src src/1 src/2/3
```

Comment: I don't get the point of using `find`.

Comment: @Gilles, just to get a list of files only at the level of the directory.  updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
> tar -cf - src/1 src/2/3 | (mkdir dst; cd dst; tar -xv --strip-components=1  -f -)
```

Comment: Overly complicated for a simple copy, but ok. Except the question was about moving the files.

Comment: Also, that will take every subdirectory under src/1 etc, which I believe the OP does not want.

Comment: @glenn jackman, I think he does want to move the whole src/1 subtree although I agree with @Giles that this is copying, not moving, so not really a solution.

Comment: Actually, I'm interested in both mv and cp. Both with or without subdirectories. So this solution is useful, too.